# Can't connect to certain databases/apps with https proxy

Tags: https, proxy

I have recently been sharing the connection of my mobile device to my laptop, when i'm out and about, through the use of an app called netshare. It provides a https proxy I believe through which it acts as a network repeater?(not sure about this part). I can access webpages and such quite easily. However, I have realised that I cannot connect to some apps. For example, I cannot use spotify. Installing some other apps like games etc also prove to fail. I have done a bit of research and found that apparently I could only surf the web with a https proxy. However, I found this to be unambiguous. Does this mean that I can only make https requests? Or is this because of https using TCP over UDP? What are the limitations and what can I do to possibly solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the [NetShare - no-root-tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en) app? It seems your problem is a bit off-topic here as it's specific to that app. It might be better to contact app support instead. From the app comments, they seem to have a trial and a pro version, which might affect your usage.

Comment: Yeah I am. I know that the difference between app versions do not matter. I want to know if a https proxy is limited to such. I will defitnely contact their support though. Thanks!